# Fixed header gets cut off on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have customized a WordPress theme that has a fixed header (which includes logo and navbar) and everything works fine on desktop Chrome. However, when viewing on mobile phones, header gets cut off by ~20px when you scroll down the page.

I have tried setting fixed height to various elements, adding `overflow: auto`, and even `line-height:90px` to .header, but nothing seems to work.

Relevant html:

```html
    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
        <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'pine' ); ?></a>
    
        <div class="offcanvas">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'main-nav', 'container' => false ) ); ?>
        </div><!-- /.offcanvas -->
    
        <header class="header animated bounceInDown">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                
                        <?php pine_logo(); ?>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
    
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <button class="offcanvas-toggle">
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                        </button><!-- /.main nav toggle -->
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.container -->
        </header><!-- /.header -->
    
        <?php if ( ! is_404() ) : ?>
        <div class="header-spacer"></div><!-- /.header spacer -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    
        <div id="content">
```

Relevant css:

```css
    .header {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 20px 0;
      z-index: 10000;
    }
    .header-spacer {
      min-height: 90px;
    }
```

Relevant JS:

```js
    ( function( $ ) {
        'use strict';
    
        var $body = $( 'body' );
        var $header = $( '.header', $body );
        var $headerSpacer = $( '.header-spacer', $body );
        var $offcanvas = $( '.offcanvas', $body );
        var $adminbar = $( '#wpadminbar', $body );
    
        $( document ).on( 'ready', function() {
            $adminbar = $( '#wpadminbar', $body );
        } );
    
        var adaptHeaderSpacerTimeout = null;
        var nothing = null;
        var $headerHeight = $header.outerHeight();
        var adaptHeaderSpacer = function() {
            if ( adaptHeaderSpacerTimeout !== null ) {
                clearTimeout( adaptHeaderSpacerTimeout );
            }
    
            setTimeout( function() {
                nothing = $header[0].offsetHeight;
                $headerHeight = $header.outerHeight();
                $headerSpacer.css( 'height', $headerHeight + 'px' );
                if ( $body.hasClass( 'admin-bar' ) && $adminbar.length ) {
                    $offcanvas.css( 'top', ( $headerHeight + $adminbar.outerHeight() ) + 'px' );
                }
                else {
                    $offcanvas.css( 'top', $headerHeight + 'px' );
                }
            }, 400 );
        };
        adaptHeaderSpacer();
    
        $( 'img', $header ).on( 'load', adaptHeaderSpacer );
        $( document ).on( 'ready', adaptHeaderSpacer );
        $( window ).on( 'resize orientationchange', adaptHeaderSpacer );
    
        // Full-screen navigation
        var $offcanvasToggle = $( '.offcanvas-toggle' );
        $offcanvas = $( '.offcanvas' );
        $offcanvasToggle.on( 'click', function() {
            $offcanvas.toggleClass( 'offcanvas--active' );
            $offcanvasToggle.toggleClass( 'offcanvas-toggle--active' );

    } );
```

Comment: The problem is **definitely** coming from how your JavaScript uses `setTimeout` to adjust `.header` (`$header`). Both the `.header-spacer` and `.offcanvas` are irrelevant. Can't help much more sorry, but that should give a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using Bootstrap or a similar grid system. In those systems, `.row`s need wrapping `.container`s. Add the `container` class to `#content`. The lack of `.container` makes the particular `.row` push the `body` larger giving you the effect you see.

Comment: Yes, you are right, adding .container-fluid around everything inside <body> made it work. Thank you!